# GSON Deserialization ClassCastException

Tags: android, generics, kotlin, gson, classcastexception

I'm trying to build a class that save any object to a file and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Basically, I have 2 functions to serialize and deserialize the content as follow:

```
inline fun <reified T> writeInCache(content: T, file: File) {
    val stream = ObjectOutputStream(FileOutputStream(file))
    stream.writeObject(Gson().toJson(content, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type))
    stream.close()
}

inline fun <reified T> readFromCache(file: File): T? {
    val stream = ObjectInputStream(FileInputStream(file))
    val streamObject= stream.readObject() as String
    stream.close()
    return Gson().fromJson(streamObject, object : TypeToken<T>() {}.type) as? T
}
```

So far, this works in a lot of cases, for example with `MyClass` or `List<MyClass>` as content.

But when I try to send content with the type `List<List<MyClass>>` as follow something very strange happens.

```
val list: List<List<MyClass>> = readFromCache(file) ?: emptyList()
```

Inside the `readFromCache`, the class of the generic is correctly read (`java.util.List<? extends java.util.List<? extends com.project.entity.MyClass>>`) and the function returns a value but when I try to access it (`list.first().first()` which should be of type MyClass) I get a classCastException :

> ava.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.gson.internal.LinkedTreeMap cannot be cast to com.project.entity.MyClass

I don't understand why it fails to deserialize correctly as the type seems to be known and I particularly don't understand why the exception happens at this point and not on the function `readFromCache` where the content is cast into the required type.

I looked all over the similar issues on stack but nothing seems to fix my issue.

Comment: You may try `java.util.List` or `MutableList` - will it work?

Comment: Already tried that, no luck